# UIStautsbar SetHidden is not working in ios 5?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uikit

i set the variable Status bar is initially hidden is Yes in .plist file but when i invoke the photo library immediately status bar was appeared even not changed status bar value.

thats why i am wondering why its happening ....

Answer (score 0):

Is the "Value Type" of the `UIStatusBarHidden` line in your Info.plist set to `Boolean`? If so, you should see a checkbox in the Value column to the right of `UIStatusBarHidden`.

To set it, right click on `UIStatusBarHidden` (in Xcode while viewing Info.plist) and select Value Type/Boolean.

If you're editing your plist file by hand, the field should be , not TRUE.

It sounds like you're doing everything right though.

Comment: i am using Xcode 4.5.1 already i tick the check box in Summery tab of the project setting in the column of 'Status bar is initially hidden' status bar is not appearing during launch time its working fine ... But my problem is status bar is appearing after i open the photo library.... For graphical understanding i have attached screen short of the plist file and summery tab skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB7F2F7C40E359EE!490 skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB7F2F7C40E359EE!491

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Xcode 4.5.2

I noticed there is a check box " Hide During application launch" in the Summary tab of the project setting.

I guess you should use this check box.

Comment: i am using Xcode 4.5.1

already i tick the check box in Summery tab of the project setting in the column of 'Status bar is initially hidden'

status bar is not appearing during launch time its working fine ...
But my problem is status bar is appearing after i open the photo library....

For graphical understanding i have attached screen short of the plist file and summery tab 

https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB7F2F7C40E359EE!490
https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=EB7F2F7C40E359EE!491